# Optimization giving unexpected results MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm trying to optimize a function which I know the results but matlab is giving me weird results. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
max: f(x)= -1815·x1 - 379·x2

subject to: 

    -1475·x1 - 112013·x2 >= -700000
    (x1,x2) <= 80
    (x1,x2) >= 0
```

Here is my actual code:

```
f  = [1815;379]
A  = [-1475 -11203]
b  = [-700000]
ub = (ones(1,2)*80)'
lb = zeros(2,1)
x  = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb,ub)
```

How would you do it?

Comment: At least include the realized outcome, as well as the expected outcome. And while you are editing the post anyway, make sure to put code in a code block (check the buttons in the editor). -- First thing I would check is whether you need to flip signs anywhere.

Comment: x1=0, x2=62.48 is the result

Comment: Excel gives me x1=40 and x2= 80

Comment: As you've written it, the solution is trivially (0, 0) because you're restricting (x1,x2) to be positive, and trying to maximize a linear function with negative coefficients. The point (0, 0) satisfies your constraints, so it is the solution. Are you sure that all your coefficients have the correct sign, all your inequalities are the right way around etc?

Comment: In your code, `A` and `b` have the wrong sign. They encode the constraint `A * x <= b` but since you actually have a 'greater-than' constraint you need to flip the signs to make it a 'less-than' constraint.

Comment: Also have written the second component of `A` to be 112013 in the problem statement, but 11203 in your code. I think you should revisit your question and double check everything, because at the moment we can't be sure what your question actually is.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can easily be solved analitically.

As mentioned in the comments, you currently would expect 0. If however, you actually change your constraint from larger than, into smaller than, the optimum solution is actually close what matlab gives you.

It would basically be 700000/112013 = 6.248...

It is off by a factor 10, but I assume that you made a typo somewhere.

---

If you are struggeling with how this function works, just try a simple case first (that you can easily verify manually) and then increase the complexity. Either way, your excel solution is nowhere near what would come out of the problem description.

Answer (score 2):

Your linear constraint has incorrect sign w.r.t. how it's expected by `linprog`.

As with many linear problems, it's actually easiest to just make a plot:

```
[x1,x2] = meshgrid(0:80);
f = -1815*x1 - 379*x2;
f(-1475*x1 - 112013*x2 < -7e5) = NaN;
surf(x1,x2,f, 'edgecolor', 'none')
xlabel('x1'), ylabel('x2')
```

This makes it obvious that `(0,0)` is the solution:

[image]

Comment: max: f(x)= 1815·x1 + 379·x2

subject to: 

    -1475·x1 - 112013·x2 >= -700000
    (x1,x2) <= 80
    (x1,x2) >= 0

Comment: Excel gives x1=80 and x2=40

Comment: I've created a MATLAB chat room for us to discuss things MATLAB related, or for discussions that span beyond the limitations of a single comment. Visit us when you have time! - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab